# Convert Uint8List to Uint8Buffer

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on flutter app. I will need to pass data as Uint8Buffer to the messaging platfrom.
Is there any way to get Uint8Buffer from Uint8List ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Uint8List data = Uint8List();`

`Uint8Buffer dataBuffer = Uint8Buffer();`

`dataBuffer.addAll(data);`

Comment: Here, I was not able to print the dataBuffer. After doing this, I get the same Uint8List as an output for dataBuffer. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

First import typed_buffers

```
import 'package:typed_data/typed_buffers.dart';
```

Then create your data buffer this way.

```
Uint8List data = Uint8List.fromList("testmessage".codeUnits);
Uint8Buffer dataBuffer = Uint8Buffer();
dataBuffer.addAll(data);
```

`dataBuffer` should now be of type Uint8Buffer and you should be able to use it directly, for example by sending it over mqtt.